# Nearest convex function to concave function in $L^{2}$-norm is linear

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Suppose $f:\left[a,b\right]\to\mathbb{R}$
  is concave, I'm pretty sure (through geometric intuition) that the nearest convex function to $f$
  in $L^{2}\left(\left[a,b\right]\right)$
is a linear function but I'm not sure how to prove this rigorously and whether this function is unique (or at least almost-everywhere unique since this is with regard to $L^{2}$
 -norm).

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Proof by contradiction, consider a point on the closest convex function that has second derivative strictly positive?

Comment: How do you relate the relationship between the second derivative of the approximating $g$ and the $L^{2}$ norm of $(f-g)$ in order to get a contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be a convex approximation of a concave $f$. We can improve on it unless $g$ is linear on $(a,b)$.

Suppose otherwise. Consider concave $h=f-g$. Subtracting $E(h)$ from $h$ betters the approximation, hence $E(h)=0$. This implies that $h$ has at least one root $r\in(a,b)$ and that it changes sign around $r$ - in other words $f$ and $g$ intersect and switch order around $r$. If $f$ and $g$ intersect at two points $A$ and $B$, line $l$ passing through $A$ and $B$ always lies between $f$ and $g$ and hence is a better approximation to $f$ than $g$. A similar "separating" line can be constructed if $f$ and $g$ intersect at $(r,f(r))$ only. Hence the best *convex* approximation is linear, is a projection of $f$ onto space of linear functions and is unique on $(a,b)$.

This can be easily generalized to other norms - not just $L^2$.

Comment: Hi, I get the idea behind the proof but I would really appreciate it if you could show more formally why making the approximating function intersect $f$ at two points assures improvement and why the best approximating function that intersects $f$ at two points has to be linear.
As a side note: keep in mind that in $L^{2}$ everything is unique only up to a.s equivalence. In fact the entire Hilbert space is generally defined in terms of a.s equality equivalence classes. So even if the best approximation is the projection onto the subspace of linear functions it is unique only up to a.s equality.

Comment: What is $E(h)$ ?

Comment: @Serpa $\int_a^b h$

Comment: I'm still not clear on the part where subtracting $E(h)$ from $h$ betters the approximation. If you can clarify that last part I think the proof would be pretty much complete.

Comment: @Serpa $\mu=E(h)$ minimizes $\int_a^b(h-\mu)^2$ (i.e. $E(h)$ is projection of $h$ onto space of constant functions).